# Filtering pandas dataframe by exact words match

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a function which can find the exact words in the text. I have a list of words, and I want to find the exact words in the given text. The provided code match the characters of words. And I need a solution which can match the exact words using r. Example code:

```
slno      comments
 1         Dear Customer, Thank you very much. We will get back soon with 
           analysis & rootcause by today. Regards, Amit
 2         Dear Customer, I will check and update you. Thanks, Rahul
 3         Hi Rick / Wei wang Will check the logs and update with the findings 
           Regards Satya
  4          Dear Customer, Thanks for opening the case. We will check and get 
            back to you soon. Thanks Harshit
```

matching words should be Thank, get back, Regard, check, update, logs
which record matches the any of the word that record should placed and which are not matched even with one word that should be removed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you provided is not an example code, it's the output of print() on the dataframe. Please provide the example code.

Answer (score 0):

in Python I would split the comments and compare each word of the splitted comment with a list of words you want to match.

it is possible to do something like this:

```
word in comment.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough.

If I understood it correctly:

```
def lookup(tempDf, tempWord ):
    for i in range(NumberOfRows):
       if tempWord in tempDf.iloc[i]:
          tempDf.drop(tempDf.drop(tempDf.index[i]), inplace=True)
    return tempDf

wordsList = ['Thank', 'get back', 'Regard', 'check', 'update', 'logs']

for word in wordsList:
    df = lookup(df, word)
```